# SSH firewall pass through

Tags: server

Good afternoon. I am working on a project using Ubuntu server and I have 3 VM setup. a Firewall, router, and client (1) for now. I am currently able to use putty to ssh to the firewall then I can ssh to the router and finally I can ssh to the client and write code & compile.

What I want to know is how can I ssh directly to the client with out all the extra sshing?

Thank you
kbot

EDIT: output from `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L` on the firewall:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1217 packets, 108875 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 136 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11 packets, 783 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 406 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination
35 2218 MASQUERADE all -- * eth0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: are the VM's also Ubuntu servers? If not what are they? And are the firewall and routers implemeneted with iptables? If not what are they?

Comment: yes sorry the 3 vm are Ubuntu. the system and windows server and I am using hyper-v to run the VM.

Comment: here are the IPtables  [link](https://imgur.com/a/oouWrRd)

Comment: If you do `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` then we will also get interfaces names and packet/byte counts. It actually is not possible to understand what you have shown because there are no interface names. However I assume the global accept INPUT rule is only for the local interface. Please copy and paste the outputs into your question rather than point us to a picture. Myself, I would have made the firewall and router all in one iptables rule set and all in one VM. Anyway, suggest to use port 2222 (use whatever you want) and forward that to router port 2222 and forward that to client port 22.

Comment: I am currently using hyper-V and it does not have mouse input captured so the best I can do is the picture.

[link](https://imgur.com/a/faL3cWp)

Comment: What is the a picture of, the router or the firewall? We need to also see `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`.

Comment: the above table is for the firewall

Comment: Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1217 packets, 108875 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination


Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 136 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11 packets, 783 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination


Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 406 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: 35     2218 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0



the above is sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L

I tried to get to to format to something more readable.

Comment: ^ firewall currently router VM is not working trying to fix.

Comment: I put your output into your question, you can delete the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest that you merge the firewall and router servers into just one server, because the firewall is implementing the router functionality already.

Lets say that you want to keep the ability to SSH to the firewall, but also add the ability to SSH from the outside world directly to your client. You will need to use a different port for the purpose, as it is the only way for your iptables rule set to determine what you want. I'll use port 2222, but you use whatever free port you want.

You will need a PREROUTING rule in the nat table:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to $INTIP:22
```

Where:
$EXTIF is your external network interface name. I think eth0.
$INTIP is your internal IP address.

You will also need to allow the traffic to get through your FORWARD chain, because your default policy is DROP, which it should be:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -p tcp --dport 2222 -d $INTIP -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "PFNEW2222:" --log-level info
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -p tcp --dport 2222 -d $INTIP -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Where:
$INTIF is your internal network interface name. I think eth1.

Notice that there is also a logging rule. Just a suggestion.

Your return path should be O.K.

Other suggestions:

You do not need your current OUTPUT chain rule, because your default policy is ACCEPT.

If you know your external IP address ($EXTIP below), use SNAT instead of MASQURADE:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j SNAT --to $EXTIP
```

If you don't then O.K.

I assume you already have forwarding enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help and I was able to apply the above config to the iptables however I am still not able to SSH directly to the client VM. 
I did move to just having 1 VM for FW/Router and have tried the config on both sets of VM's

Comment: @kbot9000 : Can you use tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer) to help debug this? You want to observe packets arriving at and leaving from each computer to help isolate the exact place where the problem occurs. Also look at the packet counters in the iptables rules for clues.

Comment: Will do thank you for the help